# Locking / Unlocking a Site in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am working on a program that retrieves information from Sharepoint. Now I need to check the behavior of it with some locks.

My question is "How can I lock a single site within a site collection in sharepoint?" (Not programatically)

I got 2 clues,

1. Use of stsadmin command line utility
2. Use of Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Quotas and Locks

But in both cases I cannot lock individual sites.. It locks the entire site collection. :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean with locking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite sure setsitelock only works on Site Collections. You only need to check if the entire site is locked in your program, you won't face it with a single web.

```
bool SPSite.ReadLocked
bool SPSite.ReadOnly //(when write access is unavailable too)
```